# What is the difference between getStoredData and getData?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, customer

I'm adding some custom logic in the admin when the customer is saved. I've created an observer on the `customer_save_before` event. I am using the following code to get the customer:

```
/** @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer */
$customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
```

While I was relying on `$customer->getGroupId()` to get the customer group ID for example I noticed some unexpected behaviour. It was returning the wrong value (it was returning id=1 but in the database the id=4).

Looking into the issue, I've noticed the `getStoredData` method on the `\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel` (which is extended by  `\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer`) which returns the correct data form the database.

I wonder why getData is not returning the correct data in this case. I see that `\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel::storedData` is being updated with the `\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel::_data` by `\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel::updateStoredData` on certain events, but I wonder how reliable storedData is.

Comment: Did you find out? Does getOrigData also have the data needed?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `getData` and `getStoredData` is at least, that `getData` gives you the current version of the model, and `getStored` is supposed to give the version which is currently in the database.

But:  `storedData` does not seem to be available when the Model comes from an Collection-load. `origData` seems more reliable here.